# jQuery selected / highlighted number

Tags: javascript, jquery

link **`1`** is selected, when I select **`2`**, **`1`** is still highlighted.
I think my jQuery is not correct, if someone could put me up?

Many thanks

Online Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/XZuGR/

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="selected">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>

.selected{
    color:red;
}


$('ul li a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').parent().siblings('ul li a').removeClass('selected');

});
```

Comment: The `.parent()` is a `li` element, so its siblings are also `li` elements, not `a` elements.

Comment: `$(this).addClass('selected').closest('li').siblings('li').find('a').removeClass('selected');`

Answer (score 1):

please use this code

```
$('ul li a').click(function(){
    $('ul li a').removeClass("selected")
    $(this).addClass('selected');

});
```